# Download a zip file and extract it using background worker

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.NET and I searched Google about this a lot but couldn't find an answer.

I want that a program will download a zip file and extract it using a BackgroundWorker.

I have the code for downloading but could not find how to unzip a file with a BackgroundWorker.

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    downloadFile("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85542087/test.exe", "test.exe")
    Status.Text = "Downloading file from W4H Servers...."
End Sub
Private Sub downloadFile(ByVal srcPath As String, ByVal destPath As String)

    Dim wClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
    AddHandler wClient.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf downloadFile_ProgressChanged

    wClient.DownloadFileAsync(New System.Uri(srcPath), destPath)
    Status.Text = "Downloading file from W4H Servers...."
End Sub

Private Sub downloadFile_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Status.Text = "Downloading file from W4H Servers...."
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = e.TotalBytesToReceive
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.BytesReceived
    Application.DoEvents()
    If e.ProgressPercentage = 100 Then
        'download completed
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Me.Close()
        Form1.Close()
        Process.Start("test.exe")
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code will download my file in .exe execution path and run it from there.  So I want to extract it there and run it.

The zip will be "test.zip" and it contains "test.exe".

Comment: I use DotNetZip- adds dll but works fine. As far as I know there isn't a Windows or .Net solution for unzipping or extracting a file form a .zip file.

Comment: I have used SharpZipLib (http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/) and it worked great.  You probably don't really need a BackgroundWorker to do this unless it is a really large file. Unzipping a typical .exe should take less than a second.

Comment: You need to concentrate *not* on *how to unzip file using background worker* but on 2 separate issues -  *using background worker* --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx and *unzipping file*. Once you have code that unzips file, you run it in `bgw` `DoWork` - done

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function:

```
Imports System.IO

'Declare the shell object
Dim shObj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"))

Public Sub UnZip()

    'Create directory in which you will unzip your items.
    Directory.CreateDirectory(output-Folder)

    'Declare the folder where the items will be extracted.
    Dim output As Object = shObj.NameSpace((output-Folder))

    'Declare the input zip file.
    Dim input As Object = shObj.NameSpace((path-of-zip-file))

    'Extract the items from the zip file.
    output.CopyHere((input.Items), 4)

End Sub
```

Comment: the OP was last seen September 19th *3 years ago*. I doubt very much that he will come back and check out this answer. Why are you finding and answering these old sour doughs?